# Worpress contact form 7 wpcf7_before_send_mail Bcc field

Tags: wordpress, hook, contact-form-7

(sorry for my english) I'm at the beginning with wordpress, which is a simple code to write email inside the bcc field of wpcf7_before_send_mail ? thank you
(p.s. I must use wpcf7_before_send_mail not mail tab in contact form 7)

Comment: Why not use the `wpcf7_mail_components` filter?

Answer (score 1):

> You can try this

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail','dynamic_addcc');
   function dynamic_addcc($WPCF7_ContactForm){

// Check contact form id.
if (33 == $WPCF7_ContactForm->id()) {

    $currentformInstance  = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
    $contactformsubmition = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if ($contactformsubmition) {

        $cc_email = array();

        /* -------------- */
        // replace with your email field's names
        if(is_email($_POST['friend1-email'])){
            array_push($cc_email, $_POST['friend1-email']);
        }
        if(is_email($_POST['friend2-email'])){
            array_push($cc_email, $_POST['friend2-email']);
        }
        /* -------------- */

        // saparate all emails by comma.
        $cclist = implode(', ',$cc_email);

        $data = $contactformsubmition->get_posted_data();

        if (empty($data))
            return;

        $mail = $currentformInstance->prop('mail');

        if(!empty($cclist)){
            $mail['additional_headers'] = "Cc: $cclist";
        }

        // Save the email body
        $currentformInstance->set_properties(array(
            "mail" => $mail
        ));

        // return current cf7 instance
        return $currentformInstance;
    } 
}
}
```

> this hook (wpcf7_before_send_mail) will run before the email is sent, so you can also modify the current form data.